# How can I remove rows of a matrix in Matlab when the difference between two consecutive rows is more than a threshold?

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops

Suppose a data like:

```
X y
1 5
2 6
3 1
4 7
5 3
6 8
```

I want to remove  `3 1` and `5 3` because their difference with the previous row is more than 3. In fact, I want to draw a plot with them and want it to be smooth.

I tried

```
 for qq = 1:size(data,1)
        if data(qq,2) - data(qq-1,2) > 3
            data(qq,:)=[];
        end
 end
```

However, it gives:

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

Moreover, I guess the size of array changes as I remove some elements.

**In the end, the difference between no consecutive elements must be greater than threshold.**

In practice I want to smooth the following picture where there is high fluctuate
[image]

Comment: Start your loop at 2. If you start at 1, `qq-1` gives you an index of 0, which is illegal.

Comment: @beaker, thanks, I think I have another problem as I remove some elements the size of array changes

Comment: Do you want to check for the second column only? why do you want to keep `4 7`  and `6 8`?

Comment: @SardarUsama yes, second column only. I want to draw a plot with them and want it to be smooth.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your exact requirements

Comment: What if the data does `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 3 4 5 6 7]`. There's a jump there, but removing one element doesn't make it smooth.

Comment: "In the end, the difference between no consecutive elements must be greater than threshold." This means that, in principle, you could end up deleting most of your data. Are you sure that it is always only one element that is off (outlier)? I'm not sure this is the best way to process your data. Maybe you mean to fit a curve in a way that is robust to outliers, such as [robust LOESS](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/lowess-smoothing.html)?

Comment: @Ahmad Then perform the loop *backwards*. `for qq = size(data,1):-1:2`

Comment: @CrisLuengo I refined my question

Comment: So it is the upper elements you want to preserve, the outliers are always lower-valued? It's a weird artifact, what causes it?

Comment: @CrisLuengo sorry, it was late and I abandon it, yes I want to preserve the upper points

Comment: That’s all right, we’re all in different time zones, sometimes you need to wait a few hours for someone to wake up. :)

Answer (score 2):

One very simple filter from Mathematical morphology that you could try is the closing with a structuring element of size 2. It changes the value of any sample that is lower than both neighbors to the lowest of its two neighbors. Other values are not changed. Thus, it doesn't use a threshold to determine what samples are wrong, it only looks that the sample is lower than both neighbors:

```matlab
y = [5, 6, 1, 7, 3, 8]; % OP's second column

y1 = y;
y1(end+1) = -inf;              % enforce boundary condition
y1 = max(y1,circshift(y1,1));  % dilation
y1 = min(y1,circshift(y1,-1)); % erosion
y1 = y1(1:end-1);              % undo boundary condition change
```

This returns `y1 = [5   6   6   7   7   8]`.

If you want to prevent changing your signal for small deviations, you can apply your threshold as a second step:

```matlab
I = y1 - y < 3;
y1(I) = y(I);
```

This finds the places where we changed the signal, but the change was less than the threshold of 3. At those places we write back the original value.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors:

- Your index needs to start from 2, so that you aren't trying to index 0 for a previous index.
- You need to check that the *absolute value* of the difference is greater than 3.
- Since your `data` matrix is changing sizes, you can't use a for loop with a fixed number of iterations. Use a while loop instead.

This should give you the results you want:

```
qq = 2;
while qq <= size(data, 1)
  if abs(data(qq, 2) - data(qq-1, 2)) > 3,
    data(qq, :) = [];
  else
    qq = qq+1;
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you I'm vary novice in Matab. Could you please include the data so I check if the desired rows will eliminate? I guess it may removes more rows...

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Actually, I had to increase `qq` only when I don't delete an element, since deleting technically moves the next value into the current spot. And yes, it's slow, but meets the requirements as illustrated in the example.

Comment: As the most important condition, in the end, the difference between no consecutive elements must be greater than threshold

Comment: @Ahmad: Yes, the above solution should ensure that condition. Did you try it?

Comment: I refined my question to state my problem, you solution still leave a gap between the curves where there is flunctuate

Comment: @Ahmad: A graph doesn't help me much. I need *data* to test, and the above code works on the only data you provided. I think [the solution suggested by Cris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56119102/how-can-i-remove-rows-of-a-matrix-in-matlab-when-the-difference-between-two-cons#comment98872206_56119102) is probably what you will need.

Comment: Sorry, it was late and I couldn't continue. I think, the problem of your code is that if the up and down are interleaving, then you remove all of them. [6 2 7 1 8 3], while you need to remove [2 1 3].

Comment: you just need to remove `abs`, and remove the lower point (qq-1)